# Add properties in object with the help of a for loop and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, reference

I am trying to add properties to an object that come from an array.
This is the code I am using:

```
var data = {};
var arr_years = [2013, 2014, 2015];
var arr_quarters2013 = ['Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];
var arr_quarters2014 = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];
var arr_quarters2015 = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];

function createYearObjects() {
    for (var i in arr_years) {
        data[arr_years[i]] = '';
    }
}
```

I am trying to add the quarters for each year from an array to the right property in my object. Say in 2013 I only have Q2, Q3 and Q4. So that was my first try. I thought keeping it simple would do the trick:

```
function fillYearObjectsWithQuarters() {
    for (var prop in data) {
        data[prop] = arr_quarters[prop];
    }
}
```

Since that did not work out, I tried to put it together as a string but all my ideas ended only up in node giving me the string 'arr_quarters2013' - 'arr_quarters2015' which is not what I want, I want to get a reference to the array with that name!

```
function fillYearObjectsWithQuarters() {
    for (var prop in data) {
        var temp = prop.toString();
        var tempString = 'arr_quarters'+temp.toString();
        console.log(tempString);
    }
}
```

Also thought why not give it a shot and get rid of any possible async. Well this task shouldn't get me near any async-problems but still tried.

```
createYearObjects();
setTimeout(function() {
    fillYearObjectsWithQuarters();
}, 250);
```

Comment: Please, add a tag stating the language you're using, to attract the right people.

Comment: @nococo: Do you want data to look like this finally? data: {"2013": ["Q2","Q3","Q4"], "2014":["Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"],"2015":["Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"]} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is according to the parameters you've provided, thus the use of eval (not so good)...
[JSFiddle code - eval solution](http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/6f3nx7xe/)

```
var data = {};
var arr_years = [2013, 2014, 2015];
var arr_quarters2013 = ['Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];
var arr_quarters2014 = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];
var arr_quarters2015 = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];
var current_year;
var quarter_year;


function createYearObjects(yearsArray) {
    for (var i=0;i<yearsArray.length;i++) {
        current_year = yearsArray[i];
        quarter_year = eval("arr_quarters"+current_year);
        //console.log("quarter_year: ",quarter_year);
        if (current_year) {
            data[current_year] = quarter_year;
        }
    }
}

createYearObjects(arr_years);

var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
resultDiv.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

A better solution (without eval):

[JSFiddle code - without eval solution](http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/6f3nx7xe/1/)

```
var data = {};
var arr_years = [2013, 2014, 2015];
var arr_quarters = {}
arr_quarters["2013"] = ['Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];
arr_quarters["2014"] = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];
arr_quarters["2015"] = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];
var current_year;
var quarter_year;

function createYearObjects(yearsArray) {
    for (var i=0;i<yearsArray.length;i++) {
        current_year = yearsArray[i];
        quarter_year = arr_quarters[current_year];
        //console.log("quarter_year: ",quarter_year);
        if (current_year) {
            data[current_year] = quarter_year;
        }
    }
}

createYearObjects(arr_years);

var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
resultDiv.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. That was exactly the way it should work.